# Selecting textareas within div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

feel like im coming here way too often to ask questions but yet again I am stuck. I am attempting to select a textarea and allow myself to edit the text in another textarea, which works fine using textboxs but not with textareas. Every time I click on the div container I am getting an undefined result when looking for the textarea. Below is the code.

jQuery

```
     $(".textAreaContainer").live('click','div', function(){
        var divID = this.id;
        if ( divID !== "" ){

            var lastChar = divID.substr(divID.length - 1);
            var t = $('#' + divID ).find(':input');
            alert(t.attr('id'));

            t = t.clone(false);               
            t.attr('data-related-field-id', t.attr('id'));              
            t.attr('id', t.attr('id') + '_Add');
            t.attr('data-add-field', 'true');

            var text = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
            //var textboxId = $('div.textAreaContainer').find('input[type="textArea"]')[lastChar].id;
            $('div#placeholder input[type="button"]').hide();
            var text = "<p>Please fill out what " + t.attr('id') +" Textarea shall contain</p>";

            if ( $('#' + t.attr('id')).length == 0 ) {
                $('div#placeholder').html(t);
                $('div#placeholder').prepend(text);
            }
        }
        else{

        }
    });
```

t.attr('id') should be returning textbox1(or similar) but instead just returns undefined.

I have tried .find(':textarea'),.find('textarea'),.find(text,textArea),.find(':input') and quite a few others that I have found through google but all of them return undefined and I have no idea why. A demo can be found here, http://jsfiddle.net/xYwaw/. Thanks in advance for any help guys, it is appreciated.

EDIT: Below is the code for a very similar example I am using. This does what I want to do but with textboxs instead of textareas.

```
     $('#textAdd').live('click',function() {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "Textbox " + textBoxCounter + " <br><div id='container" + counter + "' class='container'><li><input type='text' id='textBox" + textBoxCounter +"' name='textBox" + textBoxCounter + "'></li></div></br>";
        document.getElementById("identifier").appendChild(newdiv);
        textBoxCounter++
        counter++;
    });
    $(".container").live('click','div', function(){
        var divID = this.id;
        if ( divID !== "" ){
            var lastChar = divID.substr(divID.length - 1);
            var t = $('#' + divID).find('input');
            alert(divID);


            t = t.clone(false);
            t.attr('data-related-field-id', t.attr('id'));
            alert(t.attr('id'));
            t.attr('id', t.attr('id') + '_Add');               
            t.attr('data-add-field', 'true');


            var text = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
            // var textboxId = $('div.container').find('input[type="text"]')[lastChar].id;
            $('div#placeholder input[type="button"]').hide();
            var text = "<p>Please fill out what " + t.attr('id') +" textbox shall contain</p>";

            if ( $('#' + t.attr('id')).length == 0 ) {
                $('div#placeholder').html(t);
                $('div#placeholder').prepend(text);
            }
        }
        else{

        }
    });
```

Comment: the second argument to live() should be a map. you're supplying a string 'div'

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the reply but how do you mean a map? Sorry if I seem quite slow but I am quite new to jQuery, I shall edit the post with the working example I have using the textboxs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up remove the second parameter, 'div', from the first line:

```
$(".textAreaContainer").live('click','div', function(){
```

...to make it:

```
$(".textAreaContainer").live('click', function(){
```

Then change:

```
var t = $('#' + divID ).find(':input');
```

...to:

```
var t = $(this).find(':input');
```

Because you already know that `this` is the container so there's no need to select it again by id. Also the id attributes that you're assigning to your textarea containers have a space in them, which is invalid and results in your original code trying to select the element with `'#textAreaContainer 0'` which actually looks for a `0` tag that is a descendant of `#textAreaContainer`. So fixing the code that creates the elements to remove that space in the id is both a good idea in general and an alternative way of fixing this problem.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the further information and fixes, I shall get on them right away. Thanks for everything!